# Postgresql Update Query Takes To Much Time To Update Data

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I am using PostgreSQL 13.4 and has intermediate level experience with PostgreSQL.

I have a table `(usage_data)` which stores log details for our users.
This table contains 100+ Million records.

Table structure is defined as below.

```
Column                 |        Datatype 
------------------------------------------------
id                     | bigint (Primary Key)
customer_id            | bigint 
created_date           | timestamp with time zone
user_id                | bigint (Foreign Key)
log_type               | character varying(255)
duration               | numeric
encrypted_ip_address   | text
is_active              | boolean
is_delete              | boolean
```

Table has following indexes & constraints

```
Index List
--------------------
-> idx_18837_primary PRIMARY KEY, btree (id),
-> customer_id_idx btree (customer_id)
-> idx_usage_data_created_date brin (created_date)
-> idx_usage_data_log_type btree (lower(log_type::text))
-> idx_usage_data_is_active_is_delete_created_date_encrypted_ip_address_duration_log_type" btree 
   (is_active, is_delete, created_date,encrypted_ip_address, duration,log_type)
-> idx_usage_data_isactive_isdelete" btree (is_active, is_delete)
-> idx_usage_data_encrypted_ip_address" btree (lower(encrypted_ip_address))
-> idx_user_id btree (user_id)
-> idx_dashboard_rpt btree (customer_id, is_active, is_delete, created_date, encrypted_ip_address)

Unique constraints
-----------------------
-> usage_data_user_id_created_date_log_type_login_duration_key UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree 
   (user_id, created_date, log_type, login_duration)
-> ukdx5uuutm8d5rx9yje3r9wn7ok UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (user_id, created_date, log_type, login_duration)

Foreign-key constraints
-----------------------
    "fk29o8rfxe366qmvg7fhmaafmv9" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
```

**Problem**

Following simple update query takes almost 1.5 mins.

```
UPDATE usage_data SET is_active=false, is_delete=true WHERE user_id = 201;
```

The `user_id` 201 has 1,07,406 records.

**Below i have mentioned query execution plan**

[image]

```
QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------
Update on public.usage data (cost=0.56..258643.39 rows=82093 width=541) (actual time=29869.115..29869.115 rows=® loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=6555539 read=275043 dirtied=226100 written=28004
-> Index Scan using idx_user_id on public.usage_    data (cost=0.56..258643.39 rows=82093 width=541) (actual
time=7.389..581.313 rows=107486 loops=1)
Output: id,customer_id, created_date, user_id , log_type, duration, encrypted_ip_address, false, is_delete
Index Cond: (usage_data.user_id = 201)
Buffers: shared hit=14926 read=75213 dirtied=470 written=9259
Planning Time: 0.150 ms
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_24524390 for constraint fk29o8rfxe366qmvg7fhmaafmv9: time=1036.717 calls=107406
JIT:
Functions: 4
Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
Timing: Generation 0.925 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.516 ms, Emission 6.607 ms, Total 8.048 ms
Execution Time: 30913.532 ms
(13 rows)
```

I want to reduce the execution time to less than a minute.

**Configuration regarging Foreign key constraint**
[image]

[image]

**Tried Solution**

Based on some articles, I have also updated **postgresql.conf** file and changed `shared_buffers = 4 GB` (default 500 MB) but it didn't help.
The server has 32GB RAM & 8 core CPUs.

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Please guide. Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this statement? And please check the row locks as well, because a single row lock could lock the entire query for hours/days/eternity. Check pg_stat_activity.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have added execution plan

Comment: Next time please use plain text and not an image. But, as you can see, there is a trigger that destroys your performance. What is this trigger doing and why is it so slow?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have not created any trigger. It is foreign key which refer's to user_id.. also regarding this foreign key i have specified configuration's

Comment: Could you post the query plan as plain text?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Sure i have updated please check now